# Measure error when aggregating by different level

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have the following situation:
I am working with a database of sales and costs grouped by product. Each product is then grouped by order.

Products sold are "frigates", hence the date accrual takes into account the beginning and final (delivery) date = Working In Process

I have two different information related to each order; one is the "accrued" data and the other one is the "expected" data. Given the date accrue system, each month I might be in a situation where I sent an invoice for a value which is inconsistent with the (real) "total order value" times (*) the % of WIP.

*Example:
TOTAL Value:  100€
WIP:  60€ (60%)
tenure:  2 months
Invoice:  first month 10; second Month 20 = total 30 which is different from 60*

I have created the following Measures

`Total_accrued_Sales:= Sum(Accrued Sales) > basically all invoices sent`

`Total_forecast_Sales:=sum(order) > the open order still not invoiced to clients`

All measures are linearly split between months (based on the beginning and delivery date).

*Example: order date from Jan-20 to march-20 > 3 Months
Total_accrued_Sales in Jan is basically 1/3 of total sent invoices
the same applied to the forecast measure;
This is regardless of when invoice is sent to client.*

**My problem** is that i have to transform this linear division into a different way:

```
'''
Var Full_C_A > sum of all sent invoices
Var ToT.Acq > sum of "total_accrued_sales" + "forecast"
Var Cumulato_Acq > Running total of the sum of "TOT.Acq" by date
Var Cumulato_Acq_prec1M > Running total of the sum of "TOT.Acq" by date (1 month before)


Accrued_A_OK:= IF([FULL_C_A]<=[Cumulato_Acq];
[ToT.Acq];
IF([FULL_C_A]-[Cumulato_Acq_prec1M]<0;
    [FULL_C_A]-[Cumulato_Acq_prec1M];
    0)
 )
'''
```

This Measure perfectly works if i am using as a filter the product&order (basically the lowest level in my database); however when i want to group by Order (or any other higher level dimensions) the total is completely wrong, basically it seems that the System is not able to operate on a row level but it aggregate the total than it applies the formula.

Any guess?

Answer (score 0):

OK Solved, I should have created a calculated column instead of a measure. This will solve the aggregation problem